# video play in full screen android simulator

Tags: android, video, fullscreen

I am playing a video.3gp in an android app.But video does not fit on full screen.I am using linear layout Code is:

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/myVideo" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial: http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/19/sample-streaming-video-mediaplayer-or-how-to-stream-video-from-url-in-android

Hope it help you!

Comment: Still i am facing same problem.